# Select path for storing file in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin form application and I want to save file and the file should be shown when user open file manager in his phone or when the phone is connected to computer. I read this [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Saving_and_Loading_Files), but the problem is that the file is stored to `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` and the user can't open this path. Also I found this [plugin](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) which does exactly the same thing. It store file to the path `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`. And when I try to save file in another location, I always get error message says:

> Access to the path '..' is denied

Which path should I use to save file?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to save the file? To the Downloads folder?

Comment: To Download folder or to any other folder, I just want the file to be visible to user when using his file manager or when connecting phone to computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, the answer of [@David Moškoř](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511501/3432984) work perfectly.

For IOS, we can use the following path:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library");
```

but `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` and `Supports Document Browser` must be enabled in the `Info.plist` file of IOS project in order to make user browse the saved file (It will appear when you open `Files` app and navigate to `On My iPhone`)

Answer (score 5):

> The `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` type maps to the path `/data/data/[your.package.name]/files`. This is a private directory to your application so you won't be able to see these files using a file browser unless it has root privileges.

So if you want the file to be found by users, you can not save the file in the `Personal` folder, but in another folder (such as `Downloads`):

```
string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
string file = Path.Combine(directory, "yourfile.txt");
```

You must also add permissions to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Good answer. But how to get the path of download folder in ios?

Comment: Where do you put this code?  If you add it to the main page, it gives an error "Android does not exist in the current context"
If you add it to the android part of xamarin, then how do I call it from the main main page?

Answer (score 5):

Here is code to save an image for Android, iOS, and UWP:

Android:

```
public void SaveImage(string filepath)
{
    var imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    var dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
    var pictures = dir.AbsolutePath;
    var filename = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpg";
    var newFilepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pictures, filename);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(newFilepath, imageData);
    //mediascan adds the saved image into the gallery
    var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
    mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(newFilepath)));
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

iOS:

```
public async void SaveImage(string filepath)
{
    // First, check to see if we have initially asked the user for permission 
    // to access their photo album.
    if (Photos.PHPhotoLibrary.AuthorizationStatus == 
        Photos.PHAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)
    {
        var status = 
            await Plugin.Permissions.CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(
                Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Photos);
    }
    
    if (Photos.PHPhotoLibrary.AuthorizationStatus == 
        Photos.PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
    {
        // We have permission to access their photo album, 
        // so we can go ahead and save the image.
        var imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        var myImage = new UIImage(NSData.FromArray(imageData));

        myImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

Note that for iOS, I am using the Plugin.Permissions nuget packet to request permission from the user.

UWP:

```
public async void SaveImage(string filepath)
{
    var imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    var filename = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpg";
    
    if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Desktop)
    {
        var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = 
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = filename;
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPEG Image", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });

        var file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
            await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, imageData);
            var status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);

            if (status == Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Saved successfully"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
        StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(
            filename + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, imageData);
    }
}
```