# how to save videos to the gallery in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

How to save video to gallery in xamarin forms.I want to save videos that taked to gallery.i used the following code but its not worked.The videonot in the gallery after uploading the video.

```
var _file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
        {
            Name = "gtsvideo.mp4",
            SaveToAlbum = true,

        });
```

Comment: Make sure you have permission to write to the user's gallery

Comment: which permission need to add?

Comment: probably `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key><string>reason</string>`

Comment: @sme this is not working.Is there any other solution to save videos to gallery.Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `_file` object and save the video yourself to the gallery, although you will need a dependency service for each iOS, Android, and UWP to save the file (that is how I am saving photos, I assume it should be the same for videos).

Comment: @sme can you share the code of dependency services for Android?

Comment: Here is the code for saving an image (from another question), you will need to edit it slightly in order to handle videos though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511181/select-path-for-storing-file-in-xamarin-forms/48512871#48512871

Comment: Thankyou.The above link is helpful

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is **not implemented for Android** in the plugin yet, it **works on iOS only**.

If you want to save the file to gallery, you will have to implement the saving yourself manually. For tips on how to do that look for a Java implementation of this on Android and replicate it in C#. Look into [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html) for some simple samples.